How to Remove foreign key from a table in big query
How to remove foreign key from a table as table id column contain both primary key and foreign key but i need to remove foregn key in big query.
I using following code but its not working.
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME DROP FOREIGN KEY COLUMN NAME
It should be removed foreign key from a table
